# Programmatically get the version of Vagrant

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile

Is there a programmatic way to get the version of the locally installed Vagrant without using the terminal commands? (ie. Not parsing the answer from the output of `` `vagrant -v` ``)

Comment: So you want to get the Vagrant version programmatically from the host or the guest? And which OS are you using? If this is possible, it may be OS-specific. Your question is tagged as `ruby`, so does that mean you want to use the Vagrant version in a Ruby script?

Comment: It would be for both Ubuntu and Mac OS and yes, the goal is to use the vagrant version in a Ruby script.

Comment: OK, this is a really interesting use case. My Ruby experience is pretty limited, but I'll keep an eye on this because I'm curious to know if there's an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question like this, we expect you to show us your effort: Where you searched and why those didn't answer the question. Or, show us your code written to solve this. Please read "[ask]", and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vagrant is no longer served as RubyGem now (from v1.1), you'll need a new gem called `vagrant-wrapper`.
It's a Ruby wrapper around New Vagrant installations. You can control vagrant with it from Ruby.

For version this:

```
require 'vagrant-wrapper'
VagrantWrapper.new.vagrant_version
```